# Como poner un efecto visual al clickar a un ImageButton en Android

Tags: android

Me gustaría conseguir el mismo efecto que tiene un "Button" al clickar en un "ImageButton" gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede lograr teniendo imágenes que simulen el efecto del botón cuando esta seleccionado y cuando no lo esta, estas imágenes las configuras en un [`selector`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) que usaría tu `ImageButton`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"   
        android:drawable="@drawable/img_boton_seleccionado" />
    <item android:state_selected="false"   
        android:drawable="@drawable/img_boton_no_seleccionado" />
</selector>
```

algo similar a esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar esta animación para simular un click en una imagen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha = "1.0"
        android:toAlpha = "0.5"
        android:duration = "300">
    </alpha>
    <scale
        android:fromXScale = "1"
        android:toXScale = "0.9"
        android:fromYScale = "1"
        android:toYScale = "0.9"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration = "50">
    </scale>
</set>
```

En el evento onClick cargas la animación para poder visualizar el efecto:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Context, R.anim.imagen_click));

}
```